# if dropdown option with value is selected then change text else do not change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the label if the selected value in the dropdown menu is tribute_type_value1, otherwise I do not want it to change the value.

The script below changes the value no matter what is selected, but I only want the text to change if tribute_type_value1 is selected. If it is selected then tribute_type_value2 is selected the text should revert back to the orginal.

```js
$("#tribute_type").change(function () {
  if ($("#tribute_type").value = "tribute_type_value1") {
    $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text("Person to Notify Street 1:");
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tribute_type" id="tribute_type" size="1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="tribute_type_value1">In Memory of</option>
  <option value="tribute_type_value2">In Honor of</option>
</select>

<label for="tribute_notify_recip_street1name">Honoree Street 1:</label>
```

Comment: In other words `if ($("#tribute_type").value = "tribute_type_value1")` should be `if ($("#tribute_type").value == "tribute_type_value1")` (or `===` depending how you like your JS equality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `=` in your if statement, currently you are assigning a value which always equals true.

also you have to use the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method on jquery selectors to get the value of an element.

```js
$("#tribute_type").change(function () {
if ($("#tribute_type").val() == "tribute_type_value1") {
  $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text("Person to Notify Street 1:");
} else {
  $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text("Honoree Street 1:");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tribute_type" id="tribute_type" size="1">
<option></option>
<option value="tribute_type_value1">In Memory of</option>
<option value="tribute_type_value2">In Honor of</option>

</select>

<label for="tribute_notify_recip_street1name">Honoree Street 1:</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, as Andy wrote, you need to fix the if condition (`$("#tribute_type").value = "tribute_type_value1"` should be `$("#tribute_type").value == "tribute_type_value1"` - note the extra `=`).

Second, for the text reverting you need to store the original text first, then replace it, so you can revert it later:

```
var defaultText = $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text();

$("#tribute_type").change(function () {
  if ($("#tribute_type").value == "tribute_type_value1") {
    $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text("Person to Notify Street 1:");
  } else {
    $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text(defaultText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```js
$("#tribute_type").change(function () {
  if ($("#tribute_type").val() === "tribute_type_value1") {
    $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text("Person to Notify Street 1:");
  } else {
    $("label[for=tribute_notify_recip_street1name]").text("Honoree Street 1:");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tribute_type" id="tribute_type" size="1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="tribute_type_value1">In Memory of</option>
  <option value="tribute_type_value2">In Honor of</option>
</select>

<label for="tribute_notify_recip_street1name">Honoree Street 1:</label>
```

The first issue is in this row: `if ($("#tribute_type").value = "tribute_type_value1") {`. You should compare `===`, not assign `=`. The second issue is in `value` usage: in jQuery you can just use `val()` instead.